# GDB - $EBP does not exist in register

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, cpu-registers

I have been trying to debug an C application on `aarch64` and I want to get the $ebp value. However, when I tried to use the following command, I get an error:

```
(gdb) x/xw $ebp
Value can't be converted to integer.
```

I have also tried to substitute the value $ebp with `$rbp`, `$bp` however I still get the same error. I tried to display my register but it seems EBP doesn't exist:

```
(gdb) info registers
x0             0xfffffffff603      281474976708099
x1             0xfffffffff348      281474976707400
x2             0xfffffffff360      281474976707424
x3             0xaaaaaaaaa970      187649984473456
x4             0x0                 0
x5             0xa77fd21706390403  -6377147551002852349
x6             0xfffff7fb2788      281474842175368
x7             0x4554415649        297766311497
x8             0xd7                215
x9             0x0                 0
x10            0x0                 0
x11            0x0                 0
x12            0x2740              10048
x13            0x0                 0
x14            0x0                 0
x15            0x6fffff47          1879048007
x16            0x0                 0
x17            0x0                 0
x18            0x0                 0
x19            0xaaaaaaaaa9b0      187649984473520
x20            0x0                 0
x21            0xaaaaaaaaa7f0      187649984473072
x22            0x0                 0
x23            0x0                 0
x24            0x0                 0
x25            0x0                 0
x26            0x0                 0
x27            0x0                 0
x28            0x0                 0
x29            0xffffffffca90      281474976696976
x30            0xaaaaaaaaa990      187649984473488
sp             0xffffffffca90      0xffffffffca90
pc             0xaaaaaaaaa918      0xaaaaaaaaa918 <write+20>
cpsr           0x60000000          [ EL=0 C Z ]
fpsr           0x0                 0
fpcr           0x0                 0
```

This is my gdb version:

```
# gdb -v
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu2) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Why would you expect an x86 register to exist on AArch64?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very familiar with CPU registers. Can you explain further by what you meant @EOF

Comment: Different CPU architectures have different register sets, they're one of the most fundamental parts of what a CPU architecture is and what distinguishes one architecture from another. AArch64 does not have a register called "ebp", nor one called "bp" or "rbp". The *real* question is: What do you want from a specific register? Why do you *care* about something you have heard referred to as "ebp"?

Comment: It is because I am trying to conduct a buffer overflow attack on this compiled C. So I need to see whether I was able to manipulate the return address thus I need to see what's in the EBP when I add in my shellcode @EOF

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. On x86, the return address is not in ebp, it's on the stack before the return. On AArch64, the return address is in the link register.

Comment: Sorry I mean the return address is $ebp+4. That was what I have been taught in my school. Anyways do you know how I can access the link register then? @EOF

Comment: The link register is `x30` in your `info register` output. If you want to know more, I recommend obtaining a copy of the "Procedure Call Standard for the
ARM 64-bit Architecture" and possibly the "ARM Architecture Reference Manual ARMv8, for ARMv8-A architecture profile"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have been trying to debug an C application on aarch64 and I want to get the $ebp value.

There is *no* such register on the `aarch64` processor, and your question makes no sense.

In general, in order to debug at the machine instruction level, you *must* understand the CPU architecture your program is executing on: registers available, instructions, procedure calling conventions, etc.

Without such understanding debugging at the instruction level is impossible.

To understand `aarch64` architecture, you could start [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102374/0101).